# ¿consumir web service echo en java con angular 2?

Tags: java, webservice, angularjs-2.0

Buenas estoy comenzando  con los web service , cree uno en java, la cual quiero conectarme con angular2, pero me arroja un error.

[image: un simple web service echo en java]

[image: Trato de consumir ese servicio pero me arroja un error ,me podrían decir como solucionarlo.gracias de antemano]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje el codigo en foramto de texto y no una imagen del mismo, en este caso la imagen que se muesta el codigo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y cambiando la imagen por el codigo en formato de texto. Saludos

Comment: El problema es porque hay una protección de navegador a consumir en otros sitios ya sea diferentes web otros o dominios hay formas de habilitarlo pero lo más fácil es hacer proxy desde ya sea el constructor que estas utilizando angular-cli o Webpack de tal manera que quede Localhost:888/angular Y
Localhost:888/javaapi y eso si te permitirá hacer el navegador
Suerte

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema de configuración de los headers.
Para solucionarlo tienes que buscar el .htaccess de tu servidor (el servidor de la API) e incluir esta linea:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"